# Reverting the setTimeout method in Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So `onClick` of an element i:

```
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.outline').toggleClass('card_active_first');
  }, 500);

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.outline').toggleClass('card_active_first card_active');
    $('.info').toggleClass('fade_show');
    $('.info_1').toggleClass('fade_show');
    $('.info_types').toggleClass('fade_show');
  }, 1000);
```

Which basically, is a square box that rotates 90deg then removes and adds class that rotates 180 deg.

CSS :

```
.card_active_first {
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  background: white!important;
}
.info_card_active {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  visibility: visible!important;
}
```

My question is: within the final timeout I hide other classes on my page. How do I get it so when i'm toggling them all back again with the `onClick` the timeout fires but in revert so the `card_active_first` and `card_active` toggle then everything else comes back in?

Comment: Do you mean you're looking to toggle these classes in **reverse** order on a second click event?

Comment: @sm1215 yes, sorry if I wasn't clear enough on my question.

Comment: Ah no problem, was thinking revert could mean something else too and that would change things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this by wrapping your timers in an if statement and by changing the order of toggles. Just check to see if `.outline` has the `card_active_first` class, if it does, execute the toggles in one order. If not, execute them in reverse.

This might look something like this

```
//The outline element seems like it is used often enough to store in a variable
var $outline = $('.outline');

if($outline.hasClass('card_active_first'){

    setTimeout(function() {
        $outline.toggleClass('card_active_first');
    }, 500);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $outline.toggleClass('card_active_first card_active');
        $('.info').toggleClass('fade_show');
        $('.info_1').toggleClass('fade_show');
        $('.info_types').toggleClass('fade_show');
    }, 1000);

} else {

    setTimeout(function() {
        //Judging from the question, I'm guessing you want this line to run first?
        $outline.toggleClass('card_active_first card_active');

        //Followed by these lines?
        $('.info').toggleClass('fade_show');
        $('.info_1').toggleClass('fade_show');
        $('.info_types').toggleClass('fade_show');
    }, 500);

    setTimeout(function() {
       $outline.toggleClass('card_active_first');
    }, 1000);

}
```

Also, if you like, I believe you can combine your 3 toggles that are similar into 1 line. So this...

```
$('.info').toggleClass('fade_show');
$('.info_1').toggleClass('fade_show');
$('.info_types').toggleClass('fade_show');
```

becomes this...

```
$('.info, .info_1, .info_types').toggleClass('fade_show');
```

Comment: Cheers man! Doing a conditional statement didn't even cross my mind haha! Thanks for the help!